# Using tf.timestamp() in the graph in tensorflow v2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to benchmark specific blocks in my `tf` model. Therefore, I am trying to use `tf.timestamp()`. I need to include it in the graph execution so that it will be executed every time I call the model.

I can actually do it by using `tf.compat.v1.Print()` as following,

```py
x = self.mp1(x)
x = tf.compat.v1.Print(x, [tf.timestamp()])
x = self.c3(x)
```

But this is printing the value and this causes some overhead. Instead, I want to store it to some variable so that I can work with it after execution. Is there any other way to embed `tf.timestamp()` to the graph of `tf2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after trying couple of things. What I did is:

- Defined a custom layer as

```
class TimeStamp(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TimeStamp, self).__init__()
        self.ts = tf.Variable(initial_value=0., dtype=tf.float64, trainable=False)

    def call(self, inputs):
        self.ts = tf.timestamp()
        return tf.identity(inputs)

    def getTs(self):
        return self.ts
```

- Then used it multiple times in a model, then found the elapsed time by subtracting these `self.ts` values.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using this graph for optimization (ex. as a deep learning model),
you will probably run `model.fit()` function.
then you can use a `callback` function to save after every epoch.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
EPOCHS = 10
checkpoint_filepath = '/tmp/checkpoint'
model_checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_acc',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)
# Model weights are saved at the end of every epoch, if it's the best seen
# so far.
model.fit(epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])
# The model weights (that are considered the best) are loaded into the model.
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
```

Comment: I am trying to get the time passed during some layers in my model. This is for inference, not for training. Apart from this clarification, I am not sure how this answer is related to my question. I think there is a misunderstanding here. You see, I am trying to store the timestamp value, not the weights.